# In PHP, how can I add an underscore between two variable names

Tags: php, string

I have some DB fields called

```
picture1_en
picture2_en
...
picture1_de
picture2_de
...
picture1_it
picture2_it
```

Yes, it could have been implemented in another way, but I cannot change the implementation.

Suppose I have a variable called $lang that contains "de" or "en" or "it"
Now, if I want to print the value, I could use this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; ++$i)
  echo $r["picture$i_$lang"];
```

The problem is that PHP interprets the underscore as part of the variable name (e.g. it interprets it as "$i_"). I tried escaping the underscore in a lot of crazy ways, none of them working.

Sure, I could do

```
echo $r["picture".$i."_".$lang];
```

But I was wondering if there is a way to force PHP to interpret the "_" as a string literal, and not as a part of a variable name.

Comment: Pretty sure that's exactly what your last code snippet does.

Comment: it would be throwing a notice on `$i_` being undefined. Also there's nothing wrong with that last solution joining the key with dot notation.

Comment: As @ImprobabilityCast said... your last example works, but I would use single quotes instead of double when concat'ing `$r['picture'.$i.'_'.$lang];` just to make it clear that nothing should be interpreted inside the quotes.

Comment: I just find it harder to read when there are too many concatenations, that's why I was looking for the solution with the brackets

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use curly braces to separate the variable name boundaries in a string (double quoted only)

```
$r["picture{$i}_{$lang}"];
```

or

```
$r["picture${i}_${lang}"];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

**Complex (curly) syntax**

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$. Some examples to make it clear:

Comment: ... and I just realized that I do not need the "$lang" in brackets, since the underscore is BEFORE the variable name...

Comment: Indeed since it discovers the boundary starting at the next `$` but it's probably safer to just wrap both now.